# Есть ли в Python оператор switch case?

Tags: python

Столкнулся с тем, что требуется реализовать множественное условие, которое в других языках я бы реализовал с помощью конструкции `switch-case`.

В Python мне приходится расписывать всё через условия `if-elif-else`. Это мне кажется довольно неудобным.

Есть ли более удобный способ записи подобных условий?

Например, у меня есть единицы измерения и в зависимости от выбранной мне нужно вернуть соответствующий множитель:

```
def get_multiplier(unit):
    if unit == 'mm':
        return 10**-3
    if unit == 'cm':
        return 10**-2
    if unit == 'dm':
        return 10**-1
    if unit == 'm':
        return 1
    if unit == 'km':
        return 10**3
    raise ValueError('Undefined unit: {}'.format(unit))
```

Comment: [PEP по теме](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3103/#if-elif-chain-vs-dict-based-dispatch)

Comment: Похожий [вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python) на enSO

Comment: Статья в [Design and History FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python), посвящённая этому вопросу.

Comment: В Ноябре 2019ого [Гуидо сказал](https://youtu.be/QppWTvh7_sI) что после его нынешнего проекта [pegen (PEG parser generator)](https://github.com/gvanrossum/pegen) он хочет добавить `match` statement. Может быть он появится в Python 3.10 или 3.11?

Comment: Сегодня Гвидо опубликовал предложение добавить в язык оператор `match` https://github.com/gvanrossum/patma

Answer (score 178, accepted):

**UPD (16.02.2022)**

Обновление добавлено по причине появления конструкции `match-case` в `python 3.10`. [Ответ, который дополняет в этой ветке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1265114/209304) и [расширенный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1337950/209304) в связи с изменениями.

Ответ ниже продолжает быть актуальным, как в версиях ниже `3.10`, так и в версии `3.10`

**UPD END**

Для начала, **ничего особенно плохого в использовании конструкции `if-elif-else` нет**.

При желании можно найти несколько альтернатив.

---

### Использование словарей

Довольно распространённый способ организации конструкции `switch-case` в Python — это использование словаря. Проще показать на примере:

```
unit_to_multiplier = {
    'mm': 10**-3,
    'cm': 10**-2,
    'dm': 10**-1,
    'm': 1,
    'km': 10**3
}
```

Для того, чтобы получить нужный множитель в этом случае требуется лишь взять значение по ключу:

```
try:
    mult = unit_to_multiplier['cm']
except KeyError as e:
    # можно также присвоить значение по умолчанию вместо бросания исключения
    raise ValueError('Undefined unit: {}'.format(e.args[0]))
```

Если вы твёрдо уверены, что значение всегда будет присутствовать в словаре, можете опустить блок `try-except` и быть готовым ловить исключение в другом месте.

Некоторой вариацией этого подходя будет предварительная проверка значения в условии:

```
if unit in unit_to_multiplier:
    mult = unit_to_multiplier[unit]
else:
    # обработка отсутствия значения в словаре
```

В Python принято использовать подход, звучащий примерно так: "лучше попробовать и получить ошибку, чем каждый раз спрашивать разрешение", поэтому более предпочтительный подход с использованием исключений.

Если хочется использовать значение по умолчанию в случае, если ключ отсутствует, удобно использовать метод `get`:

```
mult = unit_to_multiplier.get('ultra-meter', 0)
```

Если словарь вам требуется один раз, можно объединить эти выражения в одно:

```
unit_to_multiplier = {
    'mm': 10**-3,
    'cm': 10**-2,
    'dm': 10**-1,
    'm': 1,
    'km': 10**3
}.get('km', 0)
```

---

На этом возможности этого подхода не заканчиваются. Можно использовать условные выражения в качестве ключей словаря:

```
def get_temp_description(temp):
    return {
               temp < -20: 'Холодно',
        -20 <= temp < 0:   'Прохладно',
          0 <= temp < 15:  'Зябко',
         15 <= temp < 25:  'Тепло',
         25 <= temp:       'Жарко'
    }[True]
```

Этот словарь после вычисления будет иметь два ключа `True` и `False`. Нас интересует ключ `True`. Будьте внимательны, что **условия не перекрываются**!

Подобные словари могут проверять произвольное свойство, например, тип ([источник примера](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/269708/)):

```
selector = {
    type(x) == str  : "it's a str",
    type(x) == tuple: "it's a tuple",
    type(x) == dict : "it's a dict"
}[1]   # можно использовать число 1 как синоним True
```

При необходимости более сложных действий хранить функцию в качестве значения по каждому ключу:

```
import operator

operations = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '*': lambda x, y: x * y,
    # ...
}

def calc(operation, a, b): 
    return operations[operation](a, b)
```

*Будьте внимательны при использовании словаря с функциями — убедитесь, что вы не вызываете эти функции внутри словаря, а передаёте по ключу; иначе все функции будут выполняться каждый раз при конструировании словаря.*

---

### Другие способы

Приведены скорее для ознакомления, чем для реального использования.

1. [**Использование функций с шаблонными именами**](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python)

   Создадим класс, в котором напишем несколько методов вида:

   ```
    def process_first(self):
        ...

    def process_second(self):
        ...

    ...
   ```

   И один метод-диспетчер:

   ```
    def dispatch(self, value):
        method_name = 'process_' + str(value)
        method = getattr(self, method_name)
        return method()
   ```

   После этого можно использовать метод `dispatch` для выполнения соответствующей функции, передавая её суффикс, например `x.dispatch('first')`.
2. **Использование специальных классов**

   Если есть желание использовать синтаксис `switch-case` в максимально похожем стиле, можно написать что-то вроде следующего [кода](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410692/):

   ```
    class switch(object):
        def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value  # значение, которое будем искать
            self.fall = False   # для пустых case блоков

        def __iter__(self):     # для использования в цикле for
            """ Возвращает один раз метод match и завершается """
            yield self.match
            raise StopIteration

        def match(self, *args):
            """ Указывает, нужно ли заходить в тестовый вариант """
            if self.fall or not args:
                # пустой список аргументов означает последний блок case
                # fall означает, что ранее сработало условие и нужно заходить 
                #   в каждый case до первого break
                return True
            elif self.value in args:
                self.fall = True
                return True
            return False
   ```

   Используется следующим образом:

   ```
    x = int(input())

    for case in switch(x):
        if case(1): pass
        if case(2): pass
        if case(3): 
            print('Число от 1 до 3')
            break
        if case(4): 
            print('Число 4')
        if case(): # default
            print('Другое число')
   ```
3. [**Использование операторов `and` и `or`**](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/269708/).

   **Довольно небезопасный способ, см. пример:**

   ```
    # Условная конструкция

    Select Case x
       Case x<0    : y = -1 
       Case 0<=x<1 : y =  0
       Case 1<=x<2 : y =  1
       Case 2<=x<3 : y =  2
       Case Else   : y =  'n/a'
    End Select  

    # Эквивалентная реализация на Python

    y = ((     x < 0 and 'first segment') or 
         (0 <= x < 1 and 'second segment') or 
         (1 <= x < 2 and 'third segment') or 
         (2 <= x < 3 and 'fourth segment') or 'other segment')
   ```

   Этот способ использует короткую схему вычисления операторов `and` и `or`, т.е. то, что логические выражения вычисляются следующим образом:

   (`t` вычисляющееся как `True`, `f` вычисляется как `False`):

   ```
    f and x = f
    t and x = x
    f or  x = x
    t or  x = t
   ```

   Предложенный способ вычислений будет работать только в том случае, если второй аргумент оператора `and` всегда будет содержать `True`-выражение, иначе этот блок всегда будет пропускаться. Например:

   ```
    y = ((     x < 0 and -1) or 
         (0 <= x < 1 and 0) or 
         (1 <= x < 2 and 1) or 
         (2 <= x < 3 and 2) or 'n/a')
   ```

   Будет работать неправильно в случае `0 <= x < 1`, т.к. выражение `0 <= x < 1 and 0` равно `0`, и из-за этого управление перейдёт следующему аргументу `or`, вместо того, чтобы вернуть этот ноль в качестве результата выражения.
4. [**Использование исключений**](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410695/)

   Если объявить несколько функций:

   ```
    import sys

    class case_selector(Exception):
       def __init__(self, value):  # один обязательный аргумент
          Exception.__init__(self, value)

    def switch(variable):
       raise case_selector(variable)

    def case(value):
       exc_сlass, exс_obj, _ = sys.exc_info()
       if exc_сlass is case_selector and exс_obj.args[0] == value: 
           return exс_class
       return None
   ```

   Здесь используется функция [`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info), которая возвращает набор из информации об обрабатываемом исключении: класса, экземпляра и стека.

   Код с использованием этих конструкций будет выглядеть следующим образом:

   ```
    n = int(input())
    try:
       switch(n)
    except ( case(1), case(2), case(3) ):
       print "Число от 1 до 3"
    except case(4):
       print "Число 4"
    except:
       print "Другое число"
   ```

Comment: Самый подробный ответ, что я когда-либо видел

Comment: match case в среднем в 6 раз медленнее if else его не стоит использовать

Comment: @Kram добавление данной конструкции никак не связано и не должно решать проблемы скорости. Я вам рекомендую к прочтению данный [PEP 622](https://peps.python.org/pep-0622/), для более глубокого понимания мотивации появления данной конструкции.

Comment: @Dmitry Прочитайте моё сообщение внимательно, я говорю не про решение проблем скорости, а про снижение скорости при использовании данной конструкции.

Comment: @Kram вы пишете, что __его не стоит использовать__, с чем я в корне и не согласен

Answer (score 24):

Начиная с Python 3.10 вводится оператор `match`-`case` (см. [PEP 636](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/)).

Кроме простого сопоставления по значению поддерживается распаковка последовательностей (например, списков) на отдельные переменные и сопоставление по отдельным значениям из последовательностей, пример:

```
command = input("What are you doing next? ")

match command.split():
    case ["quit"]:  # введено одно слово "quit"
        print("Goodbye!")
        quit_game()
    case ["look"]:  # введено одно слово "look"
        current_room.describe()
    case ["get", obj]:  # введено два слова - "get" и какое-то другое, которое будет записано в переменную obj
        character.get(obj, current_room)
    case ["go", direction]:
        current_room = current_room.neighbor(direction)
    case ["drop", *objects]:  # введено слово "drop" и еще несколько слов, которые будут записаны в переменную objects
        for obj in objects:
            character.drop(obj, current_room)
    case _:  # Аналогично default в других языках
        print(f"Sorry, I couldn't understand {command!r}")
```

Сопоставление объектов (по классу и значениям полей):

```
match event.get():
    case Click(position=(x, y)):
        handle_click_at(x, y)
    case KeyPress(key_name="Q") | Quit():
        game.quit()
    case KeyPress(key_name="up arrow"):
        game.go_north()
    ...
    case KeyPress():
        pass # Ignore other keystrokes
    case other_event:
        raise ValueError(f"Unrecognized event: {other_event}")
```

и многие другие интересные возможности.

См. также обзор новых возможностей Python 3.10: [All The Important Features and Changes in Python 3.10](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-the-important-features-and-changes-in-python-3-10-e3d1fe542fbf) ([перевод на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/skillfactory/blog/550540/))

Answer (score 15):

Самый простой и быстрый способ:

```
from collections import defaultdict

selector = defaultdict(lambda: 'неизвестно',
                       {'a': 1,
                        'b': 'text',
                        'c': func1,
                        'd': self.func2})
selector['a']
selector['d']('test')
```

Answer (score 6):

```
class Switch:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def case(self, value, code):
        if self.value == value:
            code()
        return self


def value_12(params):
    print('value 12 ')
    print(params)


def value_13(params):
    print('value 13 ')
    print(params)


def value_14(params):
    print('value 14 ')
    print(params)


test_value = 14

Switch(test_value) \
    .case(12, lambda: value_12('params')) \
    .case(13, lambda: value_13('13 params')) \
    .case(14, lambda: value_14('params 14'))
```

Simple switch case

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -3):

```
#Вывод названия числа
x= int(input())
if x == 0:
    print('Zero')
elif x == 1:
    print('One')
elif x == 2:
    print('Two')
elif x == 3:
    print('Three')
else:
    print('Other')
```