# Использование словаря с функциями

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

```py
def one():
    print('one')

def two():
    print('two')

def ex():
    return {
    '1': one(),
    '2': two(),
    '3': 'three' ,
         }.get(x,'error')

g = input('''Введите цифру''')
print(ex(g))
```

При вызове `print(ex(g))` вызываются все функции. Как можно записать функции в словаре, чтобы избежать этого?

Comment: Возможно, вам будет полезной информация из этого вопроса: [Есть ли в Python оператор switch case?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460207/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-switch-case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def one():
    print 'one'
def two():
    print 'two'
ex = {
    1: one,
    2: two,
}
ex[1]() # --> 'one'
ex[2]() # --> 'two'
```

У Вас проблема в том, что в функции `ex` вы создаете анонимный словарь, при создании которого и вызываются функции. Т.е. в `ex` у Вас создается следующий объект:

```
{'1': None, '2': None, '3': 'three'}
```

где `None` - *результат* вызова ф-й one и two, они у Вас ничего не возвращают. Кроме того, `ex` у Вас определена без аргументов, а вы пытаетесь ее вызвать с аргументом.

П.С. сорри, что пишу на 2-ом питоне, в данном случае это ничего не меняет.

В Вашем случае (с функцией `ex`) нужно переписать так:

```
def ex1(i):
    return {1: one, 2: two, 3: 'three'}.get(i, 'error')

ex1(1)  # --> вернет функцию one
ex1(1)()  # --> напечатает 'one', вернет None
ex1(3)  # --> вернет 'three'
ex1(3)()  # --> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

(функции one, two - те же)

Answer (score 4):

Если `f` это функция, то `f()` вызывает эту функцию в Питоне (и возвращает результат). Поэтому чтобы исправить код в вопросе нужно (как минимум) убрать `()` в определении словаря, чтобы все функции сразу не вызывались.

Если только цифры для выбора используются, то можно просто список использовать:

```
ex = [one, two, lambda: "three"]
i = int(input('Enter function index [1-%d]: ' % len(ex))) - 1
if not (0 <= i < len(ex)): # forbid negative indexes
    raise IndexError
ex[i]()
```

Для единообразия `"three"` (строка) преобразована в функцию (`lambda`), которая возвращает эту строку при вызове.

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю что поздно. Но вдруг кому поможет.
Python версии 3.10.2

```
def ex_1():
    return  "Привет"

def ex_2():
    return "Не Привет"

fun = {
    1:ex_1(),
    2:ex_2()
}
num = int(input())
print(fun[num])
```

В функции используйте return вместо print
Может это и костыль, но работает

Comment: Так у вас в словарь запишутся не функции, а результат вызова функций, функции фактически вызовутся в момент создания словаря, как и в коде в вопросе. А нужно записать функции, чтобы их можно было вызвать потом.