# Как можно заменить многочисленную проверку условием if?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Всем добрый день!
А подскажите пожалуйста, как в python`е или в общем заменить следующее:

```
    if sys.argv[1] == "restart_ca":
        client = JsonClient(str(sys.argv[2]), 8081)
        client.connect()
        ...

    elif sys.argv[1] == "stop_ca":
        client = JsonClient(str(sys.argv[2]), 8081)
        client.connect()
       ...

    elif sys.argv[1] == "start_ca":
        client = JsonClient(str(sys.argv[2]), 8081)
        client.connect()
        ...

    elif sys.argv[1] == 'set_reg_key_net_int':
        client = JsonClient(str(sys.argv[2]), 8081)
        client.connect()
       ...
```

sys.argv[1] - это передаваемый метод через аргумент

И таких проверок в программе намечается очень много( 
Есть ли способ упростить такой сценарий? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: В итоге выполняется один и тот же код. Зачем проверять тогда?

Comment: @Other там где троеточие - выполняется разный код. Просто для каждого из методов происходит подключение к сокету - и ему отправляется json объект с нужным методом

Comment: Тогда вынесете повторяющийся код вне блоков.

Comment: Проблема данного вопроса заключается не в этом. 
Это то я и перенесу и так. Я не знаю как можно заменить многочисленное использование if. У меня в программе будет много разных методов - и каждый раз при запуске программы - она через эти if`ы проверяет соответствует ли передаваемый метод условию и выполянет необходимый код. Я бы хотел упростить это как-то, но пока не понимаю как

Comment: Зачем делать по другому? Это же обычное ветвление.

Comment: Если много, то можно сделать ветвление через список. Но я не совсем уверен, что в данном случае это будет лучше.

Comment: [я думаю это Вам поможет](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460207/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-switch-case)

Comment: Ну поддерживать это очень не удобно, мне кажется( 
И интересно есть ли способ облегчить

Comment: Ну да, или через словарь.

Comment: А как насчёт этого: https://repl.it/EWaJ/0 ?

Comment: Круто, спасибо Вам!) Попробую через словари как советует Виктор и Other!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил следующим образом:

```
def stop_service():
    pass

def restart_service():
    pass

def start_service():
    pass

def set_reg_key():
    pass

def disable_agent_adapter_net_int():
    pass

def enable_agent_adapter_net_int():
    pass

method = {
    "stop-service": stop_service,
    "restart-service": restart_service,
    "start-service": start_service,
    "set-reg-key": set_reg_key,
    "disable-agent-adapter-net-int": disable_agent_adapter_net_int,
    "enable-agent-adapter-net-int": enable_agent_adapter_net_int
}

method["stop-service"]()
```

И в случае, если нужно добавить новый метод, то очень просто можно добавить ключ метода в словарь и соответствующий метод - очень просто и без всякого ветвления большого))

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать словарь, в частности, если есть соответствующие функции (типа `restart_ca`, `stop_ca`) в  глобальном пространстве имён:

```
command_name = sys.argv[1] # get the command name
command = globals()[command_name] # find the command
command() # run the command
```

Возможно уже существует модуль, который помогает создавать приложения, принимающие аргументы с командной строки (типа [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/)), где подобная функция уже встроена. К примеру с помощью декоратора команды можно регистрировать:

```
@command
def start_ca():
    ...
```

Если функции/методы с заданными именами определены для другого объекта—обычный экземпляр класса  или в частности другой модуль:

```
command = getattr(obj, command_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Source1:
    def restart_ca():
        return JsonClient(str(sys.argv[2]), 8081)
    def stop_ca():
        return JsonClient(str(sys.argv[2]), 8081)
    def start_ca():
        return JsonClient(str(sys.argv[2]), 8081)

def checker(argv, source=Source1):
    try:
        return getattr(source, argv)
    except AttributeError:
        return None


assert checker(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.