# Как можно перенести "case k of" с идущими подряд k с pascal на python

Tags: python, pascal

Как можно перенести case c pascal на python. Идеи не приходят

```
case k of 
    9:write('девятьсот '); 
    8:write('восемьсот '); 
    7:write('семьсот '); 
    6:write('шестьсот '); 
    5:write('пятьсот '); 
    4:write('четыреста '); 
    3:write('триста '); 
    2:write('двести '); 
    1:write('сто '); 
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Вариант №1 if elif

```
k=int(input("введи к"))
if k==9 :print("девятьсот ") 
elif k==8 :print("восемьсот ") 
elif k==7 :print("семьсот ") 
elif k==6 :print("шестьсот ") 
elif k==5 :print("пятьсот ") 
elif k==4 :print("четыреста ") 
elif k==3 :print("триста ") 
elif k==2 :print("двести ") 
elif k==1 :print("сто ")
```

## Вариант №2 Используем Словари

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

k=int(input("введи к"))
dictionary={1:"сто ",2:"двести ",3:"триста ",4:"четыреста ",5:"пятьсот ",6:"шестьсот ",7:"семьсот ",8:"восемьсот ",9:"девятьсот "}
print(dictionary[k])
```

Comment: Вариант второй выдает ошибку 

Traceback (most recent call last):

    print(dictionary[k])
KeyError: 0

Comment: @Артем, чтобы дополнить ответ, отредактируйте его. Комментарии не очень подходят для размещения кода.

Comment: @insolor Сделано

Answer (score 1):

Если `case k of` в Паскале является аналогом switch в С, то ваш пример на Питоне можно в виде списка реализовать:

```
print(['', 'сто', 'двести', 'триста', .., 
       'девятьсот'][k], end=' ')
```

Другие варианты посмотрите в уже упомянутом вопросе: [Есть ли в Python оператор switch case?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460207/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-python-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-switch-case)

Comment: Тоже выдает ошибку keyerror 0

Comment: @Сергей: приведённый код не может KeyError выдать ни при каком значении `k`.  Вы можете получить IndexError, TypeError,  но не KeyError. Убедитесь что вы правильный файл запускаете. [live example](http://ideone.com/g8fdbX)