# Как убрать лишний вывод чисел?

Tags: python, отладка

Сделал программу которая выбирает минимальную цену из представленных. Но при выводе  92 и 95 под строкой `print ('По запросу мы нашли лучшую цену!', gaz_92(), ' руб')`
выводится лишнее число, помогите пожалуйста избавится от него. И если не трудно подскажите как можно убрать многочисленные if в коде.
Код:

```
price_gazprom = {'92': 41.10, '95': 44.20, '95+': 45.60, '100+': 51.40, 'ДТ': 47.75, 'Пропан': 21.20}
price_rosneft = {'92': 43.00, '95': 45.00, 'ДТ': 48.10}
price_novyi_potok={'92': 39.95, '95': 43.40, 'ДТ': 46.95}
def gaz_92 ():
    p_end = 0
    p_end = min(price_gazprom['92'], price_rosneft['92'], price_novyi_potok['92'])
    return p_end
def gaz_95 ():
    p_end = 0
    p_end = min(price_gazprom['95'], price_rosneft['95'], price_novyi_potok['95'])
    return p_end
def DT ():
    p_end = 0
    p_end = min(price_gazprom['ДТ'], price_rosneft['ДТ'], price_novyi_potok['ДТ'])
    return p_end
print ('Приветствуем вас в программе подборки лучшей цены на топливо! Все представленные цены действительны на территории г.Тюмень и 300 км от него!')
vvod = input('Введите желаемое топливо, а мы сравним все заправки и выберем лучшую цену! Ввод(92,95,95+,100+,ДТ,Пропан): ', )
if vvod == '92':
    print ('По запросу мы нашли лучшую цену!', gaz_92(), ' руб')

if vvod =='95':
    print ('По запросу мы нашли лучшую цену!', gaz_95(), ' руб')

if vvod == 'ДТ':
    print ('По запросу мы нашли лучшую цену!', DT(), ' руб')

if vvod == '95+' or '100+' or 'Пропан':
    print (price_gazprom[vvod])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `if vvod == '95+' or vvod == '100+' or vvod == 'Пропан':`

Comment: Из трех функций ``gaz_92``, ``gaz_95``, ``DT``, которые делают одно и тоже, нужно сделать одну. Если правильно сделать, то не понадобится ни одного ``if``-а.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `or` может быть использован только с булевыми значениями. Другие типы будут приводиться к `bool`, в частности любая не пуста строка - это `True`. По этому последняя ветка условия срабатывает не зависимо от ввода.

Правильно будет так:

```
if vvod == '95+' or vvod == '100+' or vvod == 'Пропан':                                                       
    print (price_gazprom[vvod])
```

Что касается многочисленных `if`, то вот вам подробный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460208/317085).

---

Обратите внимание на то, что не объединенные конструкции `if` могут при определенных обстоятельствах могут сильно замедлять код. Подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](https://younglinux.info/python/elif.php).

Comment: Благодарю, ваш ответ помог мне!

Answer (score 0):

```
price_gazprom = {'92': 41.10, '95': 44.20, '95+': 45.60, '100+': 51.40, 'ДТ': 47.75, 'Пропан': 21.20}
price_rosneft = {'92': 43.00, '95': 45.00, 'ДТ': 48.10}
price_novyi_potok={'92': 39.95, '95': 43.40, 'ДТ': 46.95}

def get_min_price(inp):
    return min(price_gazprom[str(inp)], price_rosneft[str(inp)], price_novyi_potok[str(inp)])

print ('Приветствуем вас в программе подборки лучшей цены на топливо! Все представленные цены действительны на территории г.Тюмень и 300 км от него!')
inp = input('Введите желаемое топливо, а мы сравним все заправки и выберем лучшую цену! Ввод(92,95,95+,100+,ДТ,Пропан): ', )

if inp == '95+' or inp == '100+' or inp == 'Пропан':
    print (price_gazprom[inp])
else:
  print('По запросу мы нашли лучшую цену!', get_min_price(inp), 'руб')
```