# Эмуляция switch case в python при помощи модулей ast, dis

Tags: python, switch

Все доброго времени суток!

Стоит задача добавить поддержку синтаксиса switch case в python. Я читал ответ по схожему вопросу ([Есть ли в Python оператор switch case?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460207/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-python-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-switch-case)), но там не приводится подобного решения.
Вроде как для реализации полезны должны быть модули ast и dis.

Необходимо добавить поддержку switch statement в функции, декорированные как @support_switch и в функцию exec:

```py
# Пример 1

@support_switch
def my_function_with_switch(a: int, b: int, c: int):
    """
    switch a:
         case b:
              return True
         case c:
              return False
    """

assert my_function_with_switch(2*2, 4, 5)

# Пример 2

a, b, c = 2, 4, 5
d = None

exec("""switch a*a:
    case b:
        print("Foo")
        d = 1
        break
    case c:
        print("Bar")
        d = 2
        break

assert d == 1
""")

# stdout будет содержать "Foo"
```

Задача стоит в учебных целях, срок ее сдачи уже прошел, но мне интересно узнать ее решение. Буду рад услышать любые ваши мысли, подсказки на этот счет.

Заранее спасибо!