# Как сделать лаконичный if elif else?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу сделать код более лаконичным.

```
    if x == var1:
        return 1
    elif x == var2:
        return 2
    elif x == var3:
        return 3
    elif x == var4:
        return 4
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути вы можете использовать словари вместо этого. Использование словарей действительно является распространённым решением для подобных задач.
А так советую взглянуть как можно реализовывать конструкцию switch-case на python.

[Есть ли в Python оператор switch case?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460207/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-switch-case)

https://www.kverner.ru/kak-realizovat-operator-switch-case-v-python/

```
def f(x):
    var1 = '.';
    var2 = '..';
    var3 = '...';
    var4 = '....';
    
    data = {
        var1: 1,
        var2: 2,
        var3: 3,
        var4: 4,
    }

    defaultValue = 0

    try:
        return data[x]
    except KeyError as e:
        return defaultValue

print(f('.')) # 1
print(f('..')) # 2
print(f('...')) # 3
print(f('....')) # 4
print(f('1231')) # 0
```

Comment: Вместо последних 4-х строк в функции можно написать просто `return data.get(x, defaultValue)`.