# Как написать данный код более эффективно

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-model, django-view

Как написать данный код покороче и более эффективно и возможно ли это?

```
def get_price(user, building):
    if type(user) == SimpleLazyObject:
        if building == 'farm':
            return models.Price.objects.get(user=user).farm
        elif building == 'workshop':
            return models.Price.objects.get(user=user).workshop
        elif building == 'pharmacy':
            return models.Price.objects.get(user=user).pharmacy
        elif building == 'bakery':
            return models.Price.objects.get(user=user).bakery
```

В данном случае я про код который `if building == 'farm':...` и после него

Comment: Здесь есть подобное обсуждение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460207/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-switch-case

Comment: Создать словарь и работать через него, что-то типа: ```{"farm" : models.Price.objects.get().farm, "workshop" :...} ```

Comment: Так же советую прочесть про `SOLID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def get_price(user, building):
    if type(user) == SimpleLazyObject:
        return getattr(models.Price.objects.get(user=user), building)
```

Справка по `getattr`:

https://pythonz.net/references/named/getattr/