# Конструкция match-case в Python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, сопоставление-с-образцом

4.10.2021 выпущен офрелиз Python 3.10.
В числе прочих обновлений была предоставлена возможность использования конструкции `match-case`, которая носит название структурное сопостовление шаблонов или `pattern matching`

Как пользоваться данной конструкцией?

Для более ранних версий Python, смотрите реализацию [в этом ответе на ruSO (Есть ли в Python оператор switch case?).](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460208/209304)

Comment: Предлагаю вам и оформить ответ https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#simple-pattern-match-to-a-literal :) Интересное нововведение

Comment: Тоже в шоке. Сколько лет всем разъясняли, что в языке такая конструкция не нужна, и что _if-elif-else_ достаточно на все случаи жизни. И тут на тебе... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### В Python 3.10 появился pattern matching

*Этот материал — перевод статьи «[How to use structural pattern matching in Python](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3609208/how-to-use-structural-pattern-matching-in-python.html)»*

В новом релизе Python 3.10 появились операторы `case/match`, которые отвечают за реализацию в языке синтаксиса *pattern-matching*.

Python, несмотря на его простоту и популярность, в отличие от других языков, не имел отдельной формы управления потоком *(form of flow control)* — способа взять значение и элегантно сопоставить его с одним из множества возможных условий. В C и C++ эта функция реализована конструкцией `switch/case`, а в Rust она называется *pattern matching*.

Изящных способов реализовать это в Python, кроме как воспользоваться конструкцией `if/elif/else` и поиском по словарю, до этого момента не существовало. Оба способа работают, но из-за своей громоздкости они могли затруднить читабельность кода.

За последние годы были предприняты несколько попыток включить синтаксис типа `switch/case` в Python, но все они провалились. Это первая реализация структурного сопоставления шаблонов (structural pattern matching), которая сейчас доступна только в версии для разработчиков. (прим. реализация доступна для всех с версии `python 3.10`)

### Введение в pattern matching на Python

Структурное сопоставление шаблонов *(structural pattern matching)* вводит оператор `match/case`, который работает по той же схеме, что и `switch/case`. Оператор проверяет объект на соответствие одному или нескольким шаблонам и, если совпадение найдено, выполняет действие.

```
match command:
    case "quit":
        quit()
    case "reset":
        reset()
    case unknown_command:
        print (f"Unknown command'{unknown_command}'")
```

За каждым выражением `case` следует шаблон для сопоставления. В данном примере сверху вниз идет сопоставление строк с оператором, и если такое сопоставление найдено, оператор выполняется. Также можно захватить все или часть совпадения и повторно использовать их. В нашем примере в случае с шаблоном сопоставления `unknown_command` мы использовали его повторно внутри *f-строки*.

### Сопоставление переменных с помощью pattern matching

Если вы хотите сопоставить значение с константами, то константы следует отнести к полям класса:

```
class Command:
    QUIT = 0
    RESET = 1

command = 0

match command:
    case Command.QUIT:
        quit()
    case Command.RESET:
        reset()
```

Если вы попробуете сделать это не прибегая к классам, например, так:

```
QUIT = 0
RESET = 1

command = 0
match command:
    case QUIT:
        quit()
    case RESET:
        reset()
```

Получите в ответ ошибку, связанную с тем, что имя не относится к известному паттерну:

> name capture 'QUIT' makes remaining patterns unreachable

### Сопоставление нескольких элементов с помощью pattern matching

*Pattern matching* используется не только как замена поиска по словарю. Оно используется для описания самой структуры того, что вы хотите сопоставить. Таким образом, вы можете выполнять сопоставления на основе количества сопоставляемых элементов или их комбинаций.

Вот более сложный пример. Здесь пользователь вводит команду, за которой, возможно, следует имя файла:

```
command = input()
match command.split():
    case ["quit"]:
        quit()
    case ["load", filename]:
        load_from(filename)
    case ["save", filename]:
        save_to(filename)
    case _:
        print (f"Command '{command}' not understood")
```

Давайте рассмотрим варианты case по порядку:

- `case [’quit’]:` проверяет, соответствует ли то, что мы сопоставляем, списку только с элементом `’quit’`, полученных после разделения введенных данных с помощью `split()`.
- `case [’load’, filename]:` проверяет, является ли первый разделенный элемент строкой `’load’`, и следует ли за ней вторая строка. Если вторая строка есть, то вторая строка сохраняется в переменной `filename` и используется для дальнейшей работы. Аналогично проверяется `case [«save», filename]:`.
- `case _:` это совпадение с подстановочным знаком *(wildcard match)*. Происходит совпадение, если до этого момента не происходило никакого другого совпадения. Обратите внимание, что символ нижнего подчеркивания ( `_` ) ни к чему не привязан, в данном случае нижнее подчеркивание используется как сигнал команде `match`, что рассматриваемый случай является подстановочным знаком *(wildcard)*. (Вот почему мы ссылаемся на команду переменной в теле блока `case`, ведь ничего не было захвачено.)

### Шаблоны в structural pattern matching

Шаблоны могут быть простыми значениями или содержать более сложную логику сопоставления.

Вот несколько примеров:

- `case ’a’:` сопоставить с единственным значением `’a’`.
- `case [’a’,’b’]:` сопоставить с коллекцией *(collection)* `[’a’,’b’]`.
- `case [’a’, value1]:` сопоставить с коллекцией, в которой два значения, и поместить второе значение в переменную `value1`.
- `case [’a’, *values]:` сопоставить с коллекцией, в которой как минимум одно значение. Остальные значения, если они есть, хранить в `values`. Обратите внимание, что вы можете включить только один элемент со звездочкой в шаблон.
- `case (’a’|’b’|’c’):` Оператор `or`, он же `|`, может использоваться для обработки нескольких обращений в одном блоке case. Здесь мы сопоставляем `’a’`, `’b’`, или `’c’`.
- `case (’a’|’b’|’c’) as letter:` То же, что и выше, за исключением того, что теперь мы помещаем соответствующий элемент в переменную `letter`.
- `case [’a’, value] if ...:` Переменная связывается только если *expression* истинно. Переменные, которые мы хотим связать, можно использовать в `...`. Например, если мы используем `if value in valid_values`, то `case` будет действительным только в том случае, если захваченное значение value был на самом деле в коллекции `valid_values`.
- `case [’z’, _]:` будет соответствовать любая коллекция элементов, которая начинается с `’z’`.

### Сопоставление с объектами с помощью pattern matching

Самая продвинутая функция *pattern matchin*g в Python — это возможность сопоставлять объекты с определенными свойствами. Рассмотрим приложение, в котором мы работаем с объектом `media_object`. Этот объект мы хотим преобразовать в файл `.jpg` и вернуть из функции.

```
match media_object:
    case Image(type="jpg"):
        # Return as-is
        return media_object
    case Image(type="png") | Image(type="gif"):
        return render_as(media_object, "jpg")
    case Video():
        raise ValueError("Can't extract frames from video yet")
    case other_type:
        raise Exception(f"Media type {media_object} can't be handled yet")
```

В каждом из описанных выше `case` мы ищем объект определенного типа, иногда с определенными атрибутами. В первом case ищем соответствие объекта `Image`, у которого `type` атрибутирован как `’jpg’`. Во втором `case` идет сопоставление, если type соответствует `’png’` или `’gif’`. В третьем `case` идет проверка на соответствие объекта типу `Video`, при этом атрибут не имеет значения. И в последнем случае мы получаем все, что не было выбрано ранее.

Вы также можете выполнять захват с сопоставлением объектов:

```
match media_object:
    case Image(type=media_type):
        print (f"Image of type {media_type}")
```

### Эффективное использование pattern matching

Ключевой момент при работе с `match/case` в Python заключается в написании шаблонов, в которых будет описана структура того, с чем вы хотите работать. Простые тесты на константы хороши, но если это все, что вы делаете, то лучше просто сделать поиск по словарю. Настоящая ценность структурного сопоставления с шаблоном *(structural pattern matching)* в Python заключается в возможности сопоставления с шаблоном объекта, а не только с каким-то одним объектом или даже с их набором.

Еще одна важная деталь, которую нужно иметь в виду, это порядок написания сопоставлений. То, какие сопоставления вы проверите в первую очередь, повлияет на эффективность и точность вашего сопоставления в целом. Размещайте наиболее конкретные сопоставления на первом месте, а наиболее общие — на последнем.

В конечном счете, если у вас есть проблема, которую можно решить с помощью `if/elif/else` или поиска по словарю, то используйте их вместо `match/case`. *Pattern matching* является мощным, но не универсальным решением. Используйте его, когда это наиболее целесообразно.

Подробнее с документацией по pattern matching в Python (PEP 622) можно ознакомиться [тут](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/).

[Оригинал статьи](https://leftjoin.ru/all/pattern-matching-v-python/).

Comment: Не уверен, что подобные статьи являются подходящими для формата Stack Overflow

Comment: @andreymal Жаль, а я как раз считаю, что база знаний должна содержать такие статьи. Ну русском языке