# объединение (if)

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Всем привет ,я только начинаю программировать на этом чудесном языке , подскажите,пожалуйста,можно ли объединить оператор if ,чтобы не расписывать как я:

```
grade = int(input("Введите свою оценку:"))
if grade == 1:
    print("Ужас!")
if grade == 2:
    print("Двоечник!")
if grade == 3:
    print("Троечник!")
if grade == 4:
    print("Хорошист!")

if grade == 5:
    print("Отличник!")
if grade > 5:
    print("Не может быть!")
```

Comment: Хотя не совсем ясно что разумел автор вопроса под "объединить"...

Comment: Кратко, варианты: оставить как есть (почему бы и нет? все так делают); если свербит — использовать match case, также есть вариант со словарем. Все это подробно описано в вопросе на который я кинул выше ссылку.

Comment: спасибо большое,как раз таки это мне и нужно было!)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460208/209304 лучший ответ по данной теме

Comment: @Глеб вы скинули ссылку на вопрос, который закрыт так же как дубликат. В сообщении о закрытии действительно тот ответ, который надо указать.

Comment: @Dmitry, это я его **сам** закрыл как дубликат, потому что он похож. switch case немного про другое. Мне показалось, что мой вопрос лучше подходит на эту тему.

Comment: @Глеб я это прекрасно вижу, только все ответы к вашему вопросу повторяют один лишь ответ данный в развернутом виде и хорошо написан.

Answer (score 2):

Просто с использованием словаря:

```py
grade = int(input("Введите свою оценку:"))

grades = {1: 'Ужас!', 2: 'Двоечник!', 3: 'Троечник!', 4: 'Хорошист!', 5: 'Отличник!'}

if grade in grades:
    print(grades[grade])
else:
    print("Не может быть!")
```

Продолжайте учиться!

Answer (score 1):

Тут ифы не нужны:

```py
# Такие башни просто уродливы:
if cond1:
  ...
elif cond2:
  ...
elif cond3:
  ...
else:
  ...

# Можно обойтись просто словарем, его ключами может быть все что угодно, что поддается хешированию
grade={2:'двоечник',3:'троечник',4:'хорошист',5:'отличник'}.get(int(input('Ввведите оценку:')),'трансформер')
print(f"Вы, батенька, у нас {grade}!")
```

Можно, например, так:

```py
@>>> def foo():...
@... 
@>>> {foo:42}
{<function foo at 0x7f04f0387b00>: 42}
```

Answer (score 1):

Только для Питона 3.10+: Bы можете использовать структуриованное совпадение образца (structured pattern matching) – команду `match`:

```
grade = int(input("Введите свою оценку:"))

match grade:
    case 1: print("Ужас!")
    case 2: print("Двоечник!")
    case 3: print("Троечник!")
    case 4: print("Хорошист!")
    case 5: print("Отличник!")
    case _: print("Не может быть!")
```